# Launch4J, Windres preprocessing failed

Tags: maven, executable-jar, launch4j, windres

I had an error when I use the plugin-maven of launch4j to convert jar into exe.

This error : `net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed (1).`
When I see the log, i see this error : `...windres.exe: preprocessing failed.`

So, I've downloaded Launch4J bundle and i've used the windres with the same command (with verbose) :

```
bin\windres.exe --preprocessor type -J rc -v -O coff -F pe-i386 test\rc test\out
```

I wrote a rc file with the minimal configuration (test\rc).

Result :

```
Using popen to read preprocessor output bin\windres.exe: preprocessing failed.
```

Same error.
I used Windows 10 to run this command. But when I use windows 7...no error the output was created.

May be the GNU windres had a problem with the preprocessor type inside windows 10 ?

Any idea ?
thx.